# Long app packaging

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

I'm experiencing such inconvenience. On my projects I switch from *Cocoapods* to *Carthage* to improve my CI build times which works nicely as I use pre-compiled binaries where possible. The build time itself was reduced by around 50 %, but know the time of the packaging phase raised rapidly.

I don't have the comparison for the exact same project but I have project A (19 pods) and project B (6 libraries via Carthage + 4 libs via Cocoapods), project A contains all of B's dependencies and some more, but takes like half a minute to archive. B takes like 5 minutes on our CI, A packages in arround half a minute.

By packaging I mean this command right after archive succeeds

```
/usr/bin/xcrun /Users/unicorn/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/fastlane-2.70.1/gym/lib/assets/wrap_xcodebuild/xcbuild-safe.sh -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist '/var/folders/kj/_5sjz8qx10jfp085l9z5p8_c0000gn/T/gym_config20171219-5332-1ijzijp.plist' -archivePath /Users/unicorn/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-12-19/App\ 2017-12-19\ 15.34.10.xcarchive -exportPath '/var/folders/kj/_5sjz8qx10jfp085l9z5p8_c0000gn/T/gym_output20171219-5332-1y25ftr'
```

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference was that project B has enabled bitcode, so it was recompiling from it.